# How to calculate field as a substring of another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I have a text field, `field1`, that's populated with 14-digit identifiers, like `"01234567890123"`.

I create a new field, `field2`, that I want to show the first four digits of `field1`.

I would like to do this using arcpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kind of figured it out as soon as I posted. Figured I should post the answer...

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(myFeatureLayer, field2, "!field1![0:4]", "PYTHON")
```

suppose I should add that one can apply any standard Python string functions to `!field1!` and that this syntax can be used in the Field Calculator if one toggles the Python radio button to the on position.

Comment: As in Aarons' answer !field1![0:4] the 0 is not needed in 0:4, so if you say !field1![:4] python knows you want to start at 0; likewise string[4:] goes to the end, string[:-2] is the string shortened by 2 characters, this is very handy if you want to use FileName[:-4] to remove extensions: abc.txt -> abc, abcdefgh.txt -> abcdefgh without having to know how long the string is... handy!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) approach:

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp, ["field1", "field2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0][:4]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```